# Can't figure out why int is duplicating in Java

Tags: java

I am creatings a simple Java program that in the main class asks for a string (input) and then prints out how many vowels (int count) and consonants are in the string. The number of vowels works perfectly however the number of consonants double, so the string "James" has 2 vowels and 6 consonants according to my program.

```
public class counter {

vowels p1 = new vowels();

public int con = 0;

public int count() {

    String input = p1.getInput();

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (i < input.length()){

        if (input.charAt(i) == 'a' || input.charAt(i) == 'e' || input.charAt(i) == 'i' || input.charAt(i) == 'o' || input.charAt(i) == 'u') {

        count++;

        } else if (input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            con++;
        }
    i++;
    }

    return count;

}

public int con() {
    return con;
}
}
```

Comment: please show your main method

Comment: How this programming running? Variables and methods with same names!!!!   Can you show whole program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an instance member `con` for counting the consonants, and you don't initialize it at the beginning of the `count` method, so multiple calls to that method will result in invalid counts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just made a temporary int that I initialized in that method and then after the while loop set con = temp.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are using 
int con=0;

is used for consonant count
so instead of using

```
else if (input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        con++;
    }
```

simply use
 `else {
 con++;
}`

Alternate :
subtract the vowel count from string length
'com = P1.length()-count;'

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the variable con to zero at the begining of the method "count".

```
con = 0;
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ch;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++)
        {
            ch = str.charAt(i);

            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || 
            ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
                count ++;
            else 
                con;
       }
```

you had nod consider the case when vowels are in caps I solved this in my code

hope my code helps you in this regard thanks.Happy coding